Adding firebase-auth to build.gradle causes kotlin version conflict in flutter app
I am writing a flutter app that targets both iOS and Android, and uses firebase-auth and firebase-storage. The app is compiling and working well in the iOS simulator.
On Android, however, I have having an issue. When I actually attempt to Sign in with Google, it shows an "An Unknown Error Occurred". I am assuming this is happening because I haven't finished following the instructions in firebase for an Android app. But when I do that, I run into a build issue.
Following the Firebase instructions, I added
dependencies {
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1')

   implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth')
}

to my build.gradle. But, as soon as I add the firebase-auth line, I get these errors:
➜  putali git:(main) ✗ flutter run -d emulator-5554
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.common_common_ktx.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.common_logger.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.enterprise.android_impl.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.enterprise.internal.release.com.google.android.recaptcha.internal_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.enterprise.internal_impl.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.enterprise.internal_internal.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.enterprise.native_impl.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.enterprise.public_public.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.enterprise_enterprise.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.metricscollection_metricscollection.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.libraries.abuse.recaptcha.network_network.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/recaptcha.proto.mobile_allowlist_kt_proto_lite.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/recaptcha.proto.mobile_enterprise_sdk_kt_proto_lite.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/recaptcha.proto.mobile_mobile_reload_kt_proto_lite.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/recaptcha.proto.mobile_webview_sdk_kt_proto_lite.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/third_party.java_src.protobuf.current.java.com.google.protobuf.kotlin_only_for_use_in_proto_generated_code_its_generator_and_tests.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0ec700e9714ce9064eef1af0d40a60e/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-api.jar!/META-INF/third_party.java_src.protobuf.current.java.com.google.protobuf.kotlin_shared_runtime.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: /Users/pp-personal/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/fd337f4d568e2ea40aa721a5d11e021a/transformed/jetified-firebase-auth-22.3.1-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.firebase-auth-api_firebase-auth-api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             13.7s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                                                            │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update /Users/pp/myapp/android/build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                                                                           │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Advice on similar issues seems to be to upgrade to the latest version of Kotlin, which I am already on.
I am also using the latest Gradle; per gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip

Help!

did you run flutter clean then flutter pub get and then again build the app and you don't need to add this implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'). To add auth use flutter pub add firebase_auth

Yes, I did. When I didn't add this to build.gradle, my "sign in as Google" isn't working on Android (and is working on ios.) - I get "an unknown error has occurred." I thought it was a dependency issue?

Yes, it does! After your message, I dug into why else the "An unknown error has occurred" might be happening, and now it's working!

Good it works. But whenever flutter prblm happens, try to run flutteefire command also such that any missing things can be configured but it's great it worked for you.

And always add solution if you are able to solve it on your own. It great for other dev that are facing same prblms.

I answered this question following comments on my original post.
Turns out that I didn't need to add these dependencies to my build.gradle, because they were already added via flutter.
After some additional googling, turns out my issue was that I hadn't added my Android app's sha1 fingerprint to firebase. Adding that fixed this issue for me.
